# csv python: generate list of tuples from rows in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tuples

I have thousands of csv files with the same internal format. Rows typically have eight columns with the format:

```
row1 = ['string in column 0', 'string in column 1', 'string in column 2'...]
row2 = ['string in column 0', 'string in column 1', 'string in column 2'...]
row3 = ['string in column 0', 'string in column 1', 'string in column 2'...]
```

For each file, I would like to read in certain rows and output a list of tuples separated by row. For example, the files have strings in the first eight columns and I would like the final output to read:

```
list_of_tuples = [('row1_col0','row1_col2','row1_col5','row1_col6'),('row2_col0','row2_col2','row2_col5','row2_col6'),...]
```

Not all of the rows have all four values so I'm afraid to generate four lists and then build a tuple after they get read in.

The function that I have built so far reads

```
import csv

def list_of_tuples_from_csv(filepath_to_csv):
    total_text = []
    with open(file path_to_csv, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            total_text.append(tuple(row[0],row[2],row[5],row[6]))
    total_posts = list(set(total_text))
    return total_posts
```

But I get an error reading

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in list_of_tuples_from_csv
TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (4 given)
```

Comment: please post a sample of the data

Comment: Post the full traceback including the line on which it occurred.

Comment: Responded to both of these to the extent that I am able. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call a `tuple` function, just place it in parentheses.

So this line

`total_text.append(tuple(row[0],row[2],row[5],row[6]))`

becomes this

`total_text.append((row[0],row[2],row[5],row[6]))`